# Convert string to expression

Tags: c#, or-tools

i'm playing around with something called OR-tools, and would like to be able to create my expressions (constrains) dynamically.

the code to add a constrains would be something like:

```
model.Add(dicList["x"]*2 >= dicList["y"]);
model.Add(dicList["z"] > dicList["y"]);
```

if i could give a string list of and then transform them into these constrains how would i do this.

```
"listOfConstrains": [
    "z > y",
    "x*2 >= y"
  ]
```

how can i take a string a convert it to something usefull here. - the way i typed it in the bottom works, but want to have a dynamic way to create simple constrains.

full snipet here:

```
CpModel model = new CpModel();
            Dictionary<string, Google.OrTools.Sat.IntVar> dicList = new();
            foreach (var value in request.ListOfVaules)
            {
                dicList.Add(value.Name, model.NewIntVar(value.FromValue, value.ToValue, value.Name));
            }

            foreach (var constrain in request.ListOfConstrains)
            {
                //convert string to expression ?
                
            }
            model.Add(dicList["x"]*2 >= dicList["y"]);
            model.Add(dicList["z"] > dicList["y"]);
```

Comment: Have a look at Joseph Albahari's [Predicate Builder.](https://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Comment: Not so sure the Predicate Builder is applicable here-- what the OP is asking would involve parsing string expressions to create the equivalent OR model expressions using IntVar's and their overloaded operators. It's basically the equivalent of writing your own mini-compiler to translate the string expressions to execute the equivalent OR-Tools code. It's possible, but not trivial. We're running a production system that does something similar, where a product model is translated using CodeDOM  to c# code that builds the OR-Tools model. The code is then compiled and executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far i'm going forward with this:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExpressionEvaluatorCs/#

seems like a simple nuget package to do something like Eval in python